# Facebook notification: "X and Y mentioned you in their comments about an hour ago", is there a way to go to the relevant comments?

Tags: facebook

So I commented something on Facebook that turned out to be a hot potato. Yes, I know, it was wrong of me, but I still did it. I do stupid stuff sometimes.

Now I see a notification when I visit Facebook with a Norwegian text that translated reads "X and Y mentioned you in their comments - about an hour ago".

Since the notification mentions two people, clicking on it only takes me to the post where I responded to some comment, but it doesn't take me directly to an expanded view that lists said comment, and since there are now 1000+ responses to it, and I responded at least 3-4 times, and don't remember the exact words of the comments I replied to, then ...

Is there a way for me to find the replies to my comments, other than to start expanding each and every comment thread in the hopes of finding my comments and the replies?